# How to put multiple programs into one class?

Tags: java, class

I have made two programs for an assignment. Now my professor wants me to put both programs into the same file and use a switch to create a menu where the user can use to choose what program they want to run. How do I do this? I will copy-paste both of my original programs below.

Program 1:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please type in your full name: ");

        String names = scanner.nextLine();

        String[] namesSep = names.split(" ");

        int lastString = namesSep.length - 1;

        System.out.println(namesSep[0]);

        System.out.println(namesSep[lastString]);
    }
}
```

Program 2:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindSmith {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type in your list of names: ");
        String names = scanner.nextLine();

        String[] namesSep = names.split(",");

        for (int i=0; i<namesSep.length; i++) {
            if (namesSep[i].contains("Smith")) {
                System.out.println(namesSep[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More than one `main` in one class (or even project) is not how this method is meant to be used... You should have only one entry point per program. You can call a program from a running one, maybe.

Comment: put each in a seperate method, in your actual main method enter which method you want to run and run the correct one

Comment: And for the record: formatting and indenting matters. Your second class is close to unreadable. Just because you didn't indent according to "nesting" levels. Always do that. Why make it harder to read your code than necessary?!

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **two** classes that do work in a single main() method each.

Start with: moving the content of that main() methods into another *static* method within each class, like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadName {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    askUserForName();
  }
  public static void askUserForName() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   
    System.out.print("Please type in your full name: ");
  ...
  }  
}
```

Do that for both classes, and make sure that both classes still do what 
you want them to do.

Then create a third class, and copy those two other methods into the new class.
Then write a main() method there, that asks the user what to do, and then 
runs one of these two methods from there.

Alternatively, you could also do

```
public class Combo {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   ...
   if (userWantsToUseClassOne) {
     Readme.main(new String[0]);
   } else {
     FindSmith.main(...
```

In other words: as long as you keep your classes in the same directory, you can directly re-use what you already have. But it is much better practice to put your code into meaningful methods, like I showed first.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, each Java program only has a single entry point; defined by the method `public static void main(String[] args)`. As each class can define this method only once and you have to specify the class the method is in in your `META-INF.MF` file, it is impossible to have multiple entry points.

So you have to implement the logic that controls the program flow and respects the user's choice on your own. You can e.g. ask the user via the command line what kind of subprogram they want to execute.

Comment: Declaring the Main-class attribute in a JARs manifest is optional; nothing stops you from declaring `main` in multiple classes (although this is rarely useful!)

Comment: I've never said that it's impossible to declare multiple `main`-methods. And NOT declaring the `Main-Class` attribute makes the program unexecutable (without providing additional command line arguments).

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple method instead of multiple class . and call all method from your main method should be solve your problem.....

```
public class Combo{

    public void readName(){
        // place here all code form main method block of ReadName class 
    }

    public void findSmith(){
        // place here all code form main method block of FindSmith class 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Combo c = new Combo();
        c.readName();
        c.findSmith();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating two classes, you can create single class with one main method. Where you can create 3 switch cases.

1) To call `ReadName` **(RN)**

2) To call `FindSmith` **(FS)**

3) To break the code **(BR)**

After every execution you can again call main method. (Optional) I have added that to continue the flow.

```
package test.file;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

  private final static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  //public class ReadName

  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    switch (scanner.nextLine()) {
      case "FS" :
        findSmith();
        break;

      case "RN" :
        readName();
        break;

      case "BR" :
        break;

      default :

        System.out.println("Please enter valid value. Valid values are FS and RN. Enter BR to break.");
        main(null);

    }

  }

  private static void findSmith() {

    System.out.println("Type in your list of names: ");
    final String names = scanner.nextLine();

    final String[] namesSep = names.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < namesSep.length; i++) {

      if (namesSep[i].contains("Smith")) {

        System.out.println(namesSep[i]);
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter valid value. Valid values are FS and RN. Enter BR to break.");
    main(null);
  }

  private static void readName() {
    System.out.print("Please type in your full name: ");

    final String names = scanner.nextLine();

    final String[] namesSep = names.split(" ");

    final int lastString = namesSep.length - 1;

    System.out.println(namesSep[0]);

    System.out.println(namesSep[lastString]);

    System.out.println("Please enter valid value. Valid values are FS and RN. Enter BR to break.");
    main(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to this community! As @Stultuske comments, your better approach is convert your *main* methods to regular methods and invoke them depending on the user's input.
The steps you should follow are:

1. Join both main methods to a single class file.
2. Convert both main methods to regular methods:

   1. Change their name from "main" to any other name. Usually, using their functionality as a name is a good practice. In your case, you can use the class names you already defined ("ReadName" and "FindSmith").
   2. Remove their input parameter "args": as they are no more the *main* method of a class, they won't be reciving any *args* parameter, unless you specify it.
3. Define a new *main* method which reads from the scanner and call your new methods acordingly to the user input.